# How to call this color range in Autodesk Forge Data visualization?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How do I use the color range like the following image ? I've looked for it several times in the source code
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gradient bar is made with the React component **HeatmapOptions** and in the Hyperion Reference App, it's called from the **BaseApp**.

Here's the link to the documentation [HeatmapOptions](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/reference/UI/HeatmapOptions/).